# Expected a value of type 'String', but got one of type 'Null'

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-test

I have to add new product as well as edit existing product in one screen . so I have Used didchangedependencies method by assigning the initial values to update a screen something gone wrong in my code.please help me out. so the error is
[image]

Error is showing here:

```
@override
      void didChangeDependencies() {
        if (_isinit) {
          final productId = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as String;

      // ignore: unnecessary_null_comparison
      if (productId != null) {
        _editedproduct =
            Provider.of<Products>(context, listen: false).FindByID(productId);
        _imageUrlController.text = _editedproduct.imageUrl;
        _initValues = {
          'title': _editedproduct.title,
          'description': _editedproduct.description,
          'Price': _editedproduct.price.toString(),
          // 'imageUrl': _editedproduct.imageUrl,
          'imageUrl': '',
        };
      }
    }
    _isinit = false;
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }
```

In did change dependencies method I have tried to get the arguments i.e product ID  from one page but it showing null.
this is screenshot where i have pushed to edit screen product page with arguments which I was tried to fetch this arguments.
[image]
and this is for pushing to adding product page
[image]

```
import 'dart:html';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:shoppingapp/Providers/Product.dart';
import 'package:shoppingapp/Providers/Products.dart';

class EditProductScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/edit-products';
  @override
  _EditProductScreenState createState() => _EditProductScreenState();
}

class _EditProductScreenState extends State<EditProductScreen> {
  final _priceFocusNode = FocusNode();
  final _descriptionFocusNode = FocusNode();
  final _imageUrlController = TextEditingController();
  final _imageUrlFocusNode = FocusNode();
  final _form = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  var _editedproduct =
      Product(id: '', title: '', description: '', price: 0, imageUrl: '');
  var _isinit = true;

  var _initValues = {
    'title': '',
    'description': '',
    'price': '',
    'imageUrl': '',
  };
  @override
  void initState() {
    _imageUrlFocusNode.addListener(_updateImageUrl);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    if (_isinit) {
      final productId = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as String;

      // ignore: unnecessary_null_comparison
      if (productId != null) {
        _editedproduct =
            Provider.of<Products>(context, listen: false).FindByID(productId);
        _imageUrlController.text = _editedproduct.imageUrl;
        _initValues = {
          'title': _editedproduct.title,
          'description': _editedproduct.description,
          'Price': _editedproduct.price.toString(),
          // 'imageUrl': _editedproduct.imageUrl,
          'imageUrl': '',
        };
      }
    }
    _isinit = false;
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _imageUrlFocusNode.removeListener(_updateImageUrl);
    _priceFocusNode.dispose();
    _descriptionFocusNode.dispose();
    _imageUrlFocusNode.dispose();

    super.dispose();
  }

  void _updateImageUrl() {
    if (!_imageUrlFocusNode.hasFocus) {
      setState(() {});
    }
  }

  void _saveForm() {
    final isValid = _form.currentState!.validate();
    if (isValid) {
      return;
    }
    _form.currentState!.save();
    if (_editedproduct.id != null) {
      Provider.of<Products>(context, listen: false)
          .updateProducts(_editedproduct.id, _editedproduct);
    } else {
      Provider.of<Products>(context, listen: false).addProducts(_editedproduct);
    }

    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Edit Product'),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.save),
            onPressed: _saveForm,
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
        child: Form(
          key: _form,
          child: ListView(
            children: [
              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Title',
                ),
                initialValue: _initValues['title'],
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value!.isEmpty) {
                    return 'Please provide a value.';
                  }
                  return null;
                },
                onFieldSubmitted: (_) {
                  FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_priceFocusNode);
                },
                onSaved: (value) {
                  _editedproduct = Product(
                      title: value as String,
                      price: _editedproduct.price,
                      description: _editedproduct.description,
                      imageUrl: _editedproduct.imageUrl,
                      id: _editedproduct.id,
                      isFavourite: _editedproduct.isFavourite);
                },
              ),
              TextFormField(
                initialValue: _initValues['price'],
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Price',
                ),
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                focusNode: _priceFocusNode,
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value!.isEmpty) {
                    return 'Please enter a  price ';
                  }
                  if (double.tryParse(value) == null) {
                    return 'Please Enter a Valid Number';
                  }
                  if (double.parse(value) <= 0) {
                    return 'Please Enter the number greather no than zero';
                  }
                },
                onSaved: (value) {
                  _editedproduct = Product(
                      title: _editedproduct.title,
                      price: double.parse(value!),
                      description: _editedproduct.description,
                      imageUrl: _editedproduct.imageUrl,
                      id: _editedproduct.id,
                      isFavourite: _editedproduct.isFavourite);
                },
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Description',
                ),
                initialValue: _initValues['description'],
                maxLines: 3,
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                focusNode: _descriptionFocusNode,
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value!.isEmpty) {
                    return 'Please enter a  description ';
                  }
                  if (value.length < 10) {
                    return 'Should be at least 10 characters long.';
                  }
                  return null;
                },
                onSaved: (value) {
                  _editedproduct = Product(
                      title: _editedproduct.title,
                      price: _editedproduct.price,
                      description: value as String,
                      imageUrl: _editedproduct.imageUrl,
                      id: _editedproduct.id,
                      isFavourite: _editedproduct.isFavourite);
                },
              ),
              Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    width: 100,
                    height: 100,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8, right: 10),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border.all(width: 1, color: Colors.grey)),
                    child: _imageUrlController.text.isEmpty
                        ? Text('Enter a URL')
                        : FittedBox(
                            child: Image.network(
                              _imageUrlController.text,
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            ),
                          ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextFormField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Image URl'),
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.url,
                      textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                      controller: _imageUrlController,
                      focusNode: _imageUrlFocusNode,
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value!.isEmpty) {
                          return 'Please enter a  URL ';
                        }
                        if (!value.startsWith('http') &&
                            !value.startsWith('https')) {
                          return 'Please Enter a valid URL';
                        }
                        if (!value.endsWith('.png') &&
                            !value.endsWith('.jpg') &&
                            !value.endsWith('.jpeg')) {
                          return 'Please enter a valid image URL';
                        }
                        return null;
                      },
                      onFieldSubmitted: (_) {
                        _saveForm();
                      },
                      onSaved: (value) {
                        _editedproduct = Product(
                            title: _editedproduct.title,
                            price: _editedproduct.price,
                            description: _editedproduct.description,
                            imageUrl: value as String,
                            id: _editedproduct.id,
                            isFavourite: _editedproduct.isFavourite);
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: which variable is null exactly, do you know?

Comment: I think in didchangedependencies method , ProductID variable

Comment: you have already added null check if (productId != null) , now you should not get that exception.

Comment: so is this because of imageurl in _initvalues ?

Comment: I doubt _editedproduct providing not having all values, use null operators with upgrading flutter

Comment: I tried to print the every variable of _editedproduct  but it works perfectly fined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While Null-Safety is implemented, most tutorials were made before it so in your case where you are trying to check if the `ModalRoute` returns you a `null` value or not and do stuff depending on that, good old `if(productId == null)` won't work now.
Instead you can do this:

```
final productId = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments == null ? "NULL":ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as String;

if(productId != "NULL"){
 
   //Do stuff here

}
```

If `ModalRoute` gives you `null`, you assign the string "NULL" to your variable `productId` else you just assign whatever value it returned.

Then you can simply check if the value of `productId` is `NULL` and proceed accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Following the answer, Maruf Ahmed gave will work but will not display the added product. What solved the error for me was to change != null into '' annotation inside the saveForm method.

You can check the saveForm method

[image: 1]

Comment: Code snippets should be included as properly [formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) text, not as an image. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I think I am late answering this question, but my answer will help someone in the future.

Avoid casting the argument to String. This error throwing cause when pushname is called without any argument then it automatically passes null, and when null casting to String then the error happen.

**Use like this line**

```
final productId= ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments;
```

**Then check productId null or not. If not null then convert product object to string**

```
  if (productId != null) {
    _editedProduct =
        Provider.of<Products>(context, listen: false).findById(productId.toString());
    ...... 

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the error was the same with stacktrace

```
Error: Expected a value of type 'String', but got one of type 'Null'
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:51932/dart_sdk.js:5080:11)
    at Object.castError (http://localhost:51932/dart_sdk.js:5039:15)
    at Object.cast [as as] (http://localhost:51932/dart_sdk.js:5356:17)
    at String.as (http://localhost:51932/dart_sdk.js:46240:19)
    at Object.getProperty (http://localhost:51932/dart_sdk.js:62320:14)
    at Object.convertFirebaseDatabaseException (http://localhost:51932/packages/firebase_database_web/src/interop/database.dart.lib.js:1318:27)
    at http://localhost:51932/packages/firebase_database_web/src/interop/database.dart.lib.js:289:67
    at Object._checkAndCall (http://localhost:51932/dart_sdk.js:5279:16)
    at Object.dcall (http://localhost:51932/dart_sdk.js:5284:17)
    at ret (http://localhost:51932/dart_sdk.js:62210:21)
    at CallbackContext.onCancel (https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.9.0/firebase-database.js:13442:36)
    at https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.9.0/firebase-database.js:14240:47
    at exceptionGuard (https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.9.0/firebase-database.js:2000:9)
    at eventListRaise (https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.9.0/firebase-database.js:12292:13)
    at eventQueueRaiseQueuedEventsMatchingPredicate (https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.9.0/firebase-database.js:12267:17)
    at eventQueueRaiseEventsForChangedPath (https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.9.0/firebase-database.js:12256:5)
    at Object.onComplete (https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.9.0/firebase-database.js:12413:17)
    at https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.9.0/firebase-database.js:4667:32
    at PersistentConnection.onDataMessage_ (https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.9.0/firebase-database.js:4920:17)
    at Connection.onDataMessage_ (https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.9.0/firebase-database.js:3762:14)
    at Connection.onPrimaryMessageReceived_ (https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.9.0/firebase-database.js:3756:18)
    at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.9.0/firebase-database.js:3658:26)
    at WebSocketConnection.appendFrame_ (https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.9.0/firebase-database.js:3275:18)
    at WebSocketConnection.handleIncomingFrame (https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.9.0/firebase-database.js:3323:22)
    at mySock.onmessage (https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.9.0/firebase-database.js:3222:18)
```

I was stuck with this for 2 days when I remembered the date limit on the default database rules have been expired:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "now < ...",  // YYYY-MM-DD
    ".write": "now < ...",  // YYYY-MM-DD
  }
}
```

So I just defined better rules and I got it working.

Answer (score -2):

Jitesh Mohite (_editedProduct.id) is the null variable inside the 'build', inside 'didchangedependencies' it's not null, it has the same value of ProductId

Comment: This does not answer the question, please ask your queries in comments of the question.